# Options API get_option() and update_option() Not Correctly Updating or Returning

Tags: php, plugin-development, options

Consider the following code:

```
if(!class_exists('Update_Option_Error')){
    class Update_Option_Error
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            ob_start();
            // This should trigger on page load
            add_action('init', array($this, 'init'));
        }

        public function init()
        {
            // Try to get the option 'test_option'
            $test_option = get_option('test_option');

            echo "<script>alert('Option is set to: $test_option');</script>"; //DEBUG

            // If 'get_option' returned false (Meaning the option was not created yet)
            if($test_option === false){
                echo "<script>alert('Option was not set');</script>"; //DEBUG

                // Create the option 'test_option' and set it to 'Foo'
                update_option('test_option', 'Foo');
                // Now try to get the option again (It should be 'Foo')
                $test_option = get_option('test_option');

                echo "<script>alert('Option is now set to: $test_option');</script>"; //DEBUG
            // If 'get_option' returned something other than false (Meaning the option was set to something)
            }else{
                // If 'test_option' is set to 'Foo'
                if($test_option === 'Foo'){
                    echo "<script>alert('Option is Foo');</script>"; //DEBUG

                    // Update the option's value to 'Bar'
                    update_option('test_option', 'Bar');
                    // Now try to get the option again (It should be 'Bar')
                    $test_option = get_option('test_option');

                    echo "<script>alert('Option is now set to: $test_option');</script>"; //DEBUG
                // If 'test_option' is set to 'Bar'
                }elseif($test_option === 'Bar'){
                    echo "<script>alert('Option is Bar');</script>"; //DEBUG

                    // Update the option's value to 'Foo'
                    update_option('test_option', 'Foo');
                    // Now try to get the option again (It should be 'Foo')
                    $test_option = get_option('test_option');

                    echo "<script>alert('Option is now set to: $test_option');</script>"; //DEBUG
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $update_option_error = new Update_Option_Error();
}
```

Here is a brief explanation of what it *should* do:

- Create a new Plugin Class 'Update_Option_Error'
- Call function 'init' on every WordPress 'init' action
- Try to get the option 'test_option'
- If the option was false (not created yet):

  - Create the option and set it to 'Foo'
- If the option was set to 'Foo':

  - Set the option to 'Bar'
- If the option was set to 'Bar':

  - Set the option to 'Foo'

However, it appears that when this plugin is activated, the value of the option 'test_option' is either not updated properly or not read properly.
For example, if the page is loaded and the option is read as 'Foo', the following can happen:

- The option is read as 'Foo' (`alert('Option is set to: Foo')` then `alert('Option is Foo')`)
- The option then should be updated to 'Bar' (`update_option('test_option', 'Bar');`), **However**:

  - Sometimes results in `alert('Option is now set to: Foo')`
  - Sometimes results in `alert('Option is now set to: Bar')`
- Either way, the next page refresh still reads the option as 'Foo'
- If a new page is loaded, sometimes the option will correctly be updated to 'Bar'

Notes:

- This occurs regardless of if the option is initially set to 'Foo' or 'Bar'
- Removing all `echo` and `ob_start()` does not resolve the issue
- There appears to be no pattern on whether the option is successfully set and read
- WordPress Version is 4.8
- Feel free to test the plugin yourself [Here](https://github.com/lkarinja/WordPress-Update-Option-Error)

Why is this occurring? What can be done to fix the functionality?